# Time complexity divisions

Tags: c, time-complexity, big-o

Hi I just wanted to check this.

Say if f(n) = O(g(n)) then is f(n)/g(n) = O(1)?
and also if f(n) = theta(g(n)) then is f(n)/g(n) = theta(1)

Is both statement true? and could if not could I get some explanations on that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Correction, you're right. Intuitively `f(n)=O(g(n))` means that `f` grows at most as fast as `g`, hence `f(n)/g(n)` is "at most constant". Below I give formal proofs for your claims.

More formally, `f=O(g)` means that for all large enough `n` we have `f(n) <= C*g(n)` for some `C>0`. Hence for all large enough `n` we have `f(n)/g(n) <= C*g(n)/g(n) <= C`. This implies `f/g=O(1)`.

For the second question if `f=Theta(g)` then `D*g(n) <= f(n) <= C*g(n)` for all large enough `n` and some `C,D>0`. Hence, on one hand, `f(n)/g(n) >= D*g(n)/g(n) >= D`; on the other hand, `f(n)/g(n) <= C*g(n)/g(n) <= C`; putting these two together we get that for all sufficiently large `n` we have `D <= f(n)/g(n) <= C` which implies `f/g=Theta(1)` as you state.